# error happens when i try to run my cross platform app on android

Tags: typescript, gradle, nativescript, angular14

i'm  trying to build a cross platform application using nativescript with angular . on web it runs perfectly but when i try it on android  it doesnt run i had many errors that i solved but i'm stuck with this one. so please help me if you have any idea [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG8rt.png).
i tried to add new path and updating the jdk but nothing has changed

honestly with error i didn't know wht to do so i'm hopêing that someone helps with it

Comment: Can you paste the contents of your tsconfig.json file?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `tsconfig.json`

```
...
"include": [
    "src/tests/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.ios.ts",
    "src/**/*.android.ts"
  ],
   "files": [
     "./src/main.ts",
    "./references.d.ts",
     "./src/polyfills.ts"
   ]},
...
```